# Qt - how to map ,map coordinates to image pixel in an scene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qmap

I have created an Scene in Qt where i took the an image from open street map[.png] and placed it into the Scene . I have also exported its coordinates in an another file .My Question is how do I map my image pixel with the map coordinates. basically i want to plot the roads in the map into my image .Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer I was looking for  [Convert Lat/Longs to X/Y Co-ordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953150/convert-lat-longs-to-x-y-co-ordinates)

Answer (score 0):

Does the download from openstreetmap give you any coords and scale for the image tile?

If not then you have to find some objects in the scene and get their world coords from somewhere

Comment: No ,i doenst give . But I can download any selected coords from it manually.I can download image separately and coords seperately

Comment: Then you just need either the coords for two points in the image - eg two corners, or a center point and a scale. Then it's trivial to convert pixel X,Y into lat/long or whatever. Assuming the map is small enough that you don't have to worry about curvature of the earth - and you aren't at the pole!  Be careful of which direction Y increases though - if y starts from the top or bottom